# How to hide the keyboard, editext?

Tags: java, android

I, as a young android developer, ask for help from the wise men. I have EditText, when I click on enter the keyboard is hidden, but if I change the keyboard language to Russian, then when I press enter, the keyboard is NOT hidden. I want the keyboard to hide out of dependence on the language by simply pressing enter. Please save me.[enter image description here][1]

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/home_user_myself_information"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"/>

     addMySelfInformation(EditText)findViewById(R.id.home_user_myself_information);
     addMySelfInformation.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if((event.getAction()==KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)&&(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)){
                Context context=getApplicationContext();
                InputMethodManager imm=(InputMethodManager)context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(addMySelfInformation.getWindowToken(),0);


                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Try  to copy and paste your code into a readable format here.

Comment: please do not link to images that only include text. embed them in your question OR even better, provide the text directly

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Close/hide the Android Soft Keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard)

Comment: Sorry right now

Comment: Did you check whether your code  of closing soft input method is really invoked?